# VS Code on Mac iOS with C++. How can I "cout" in customized terminal?

Tags: c++, macos, terminal, visual-studio-code

I have the next sequence of files:

1. sample.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


#pragma region - Test Functions
void fn01()
{
    int a, b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    int sum = a + b;
    cout << sum << endl;
   
}

void fn02()
{
     vector<string> msg {"Hello", "C++", "World", "from", "VS Code", "and the C++ extension!"};

    for (const string& word : msg)
    {
        cout << word << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
#pragma endregion


int main()
{
    
    cout << "Now the screen will be cleared!" << endl;
    //printf("\e[1;1H\e[2J");
    system("clear");
    cout << "\n==============================";
    cout << "Empty Screen" << endl;
    fn01();
    fn02();
    return 0;
}
```

2. task.json

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "clang++ build active file",
        "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
        "args": [
          "-std=c++17",
          "-stdlib=libc++",
          "-g",
          "${file}",
          "-I/Users/Armonicus/MyProjects/C++VSCodeProjects/projects/helloworld01/include",
          "-o",
          "${fileDirname}/src/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
        ],
        "options": {
          "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
        "group": {
          "kind": "build",
          "isDefault": true
        }
      }
      
      
    ]
  }
```

3. launch.json

```
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "clang++ - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/src/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "lldb",
            "preLaunchTask": "clang++ build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

4. c_cpp_properties.json

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/include"
            ],
            "defines": [],
             
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "cStandard": "gnu17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "macos-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

With these configurations I am able to run the program in external terminal as expected.
The problem appeared after I customized the appearance of my terminal: when press F5 now is displaying 2 terminals, in background my customized terminal which is non active and floating above, the original terminal where I can type in my variables and show the results as expected.
You have an idea in the next snapshot:
[image]

The question is how can I "cin" and "cout" directly in my customized terminal, disabling the original black one?

Comment: The "trick" is to create your own `system()`. On a basic level, it's really simple (`execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", command, (char *) NULL);`). I suspect you'd like pipes to your own version though so look into the `execl` and `dup`/`dup2`, `fork` and `pipe` calls.

Comment: As a beginner (as you can see I do code with basic functions) I looked on Wikipedia to find out what is this ```execl``` command. It seems that was implemented in UNIX systems and still in our days  works as well on mac os. The link is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exec_(system_call). But really I don't see how this instruction helps to solve my problem. How controlling the threads and processes can enforce the vs code to print out on my customized terminal?

Comment: You may be a beginner, but you want to do things that does not have a solution in standard C++. It's tragic, but a fact. To accomplish what you want to do, you do need to read OS API documentation (or use a library that encapsulates all that mess, like `boost`). I may go against common recommendations here, but I recommend that you actually try to do this yourself, by using the OS calls - but keep in mind that you've left standard C++ territory and need to re-implement it if you move to a different platform. I recommend this because this case is excellent for learning some deeper stuff.

Comment: Ok, I'm ready to explore this deep forest. But in order to do it I need a solid lead. A tutorial or something equivalent. The question still remains: should I write a script in c++ in visual studio which is able to make visual studio itself to changes it's behavior? and if this is possible how do I start? Something simple for the beginning... for example to increase the font size programmatically (this is simple task when modify the vs code settings)

Comment: How is that important? Keep your eye at the ball

Comment: Here is what I found about ```boost```: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_(C%2B%2B_libraries). Now I have this set of libraries. But in order to write the script I need to understand how VSC trigger the terminal and how it is possible to programmatically change different properties of its console display. Do you know where can I find some documentations about this subject?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232134/discussion-between-armonicus-and-ted-lyngmo).